# Ajax is not working in a loop

Tags: plugin-development, custom-field, ajax, terms

I am trying to show data associated with selected categories by using ajax. Its working only for the last term selected, not for all the selected terms. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
var selected_cat = $('#my-categorychecklist input:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value
}).get();

   $(document).ready( function () {
         var getid = $('#my-categorychecklist input:checked').last().val();
         var matchid = $('#my-categorychecklist input:checked').last().val();

         $('#section').html('<div class="spinner"></div>');
         var data = {
             'action': 'fields_selected',
             'post_id': $('#fields-list-selected').data('post_id'),
             'term_id': selected_cat
         };

             $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
                     if(response != 0) {
                         $('.block'+getid).html(response);
                         $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
                     } else {
                         $('.block'+getid).html(" ");
                         $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
                     }
             });

     });///////PHP AJAX CALLBACK START
    $args = null;
    if (!empty($term_ids)){ //terms ids
        foreach($term_ids as $term_id){
            $args = array(
                'post_type'      => 'my_post',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'meta_query'    => array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'key'       => 'category',
                        'value'     => $term_id,
                        'compare'   => 'EXISTS',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'key'       => 'associate',
                        'value'     => 'categories',
                        'compare'   => 'LIKE',
                    )
                )
            );
            $query = new WP_Query( $args );
            if ($query->have_posts()){

                // Start the Loop
                global $post;
                // Process output
                ob_start();

                include MY_TEMPLATES_DIR . 'custom-field.php';
                wp_reset_postdata(); // Restore global post data stomped by the_post()
                $output = ob_get_clean();

                print $output;

                if( $ajax ) {
                    wp_die();
                }
            } else{
                // Process empty output
                ob_start();
                ?>
                <?php
                $output = ob_get_clean();
                print $output;
                //print "No data found !";
            }
        }
    }/*AJAX CALLBACK END*/if ($term_id_selected) {
        foreach ($term_id_selected as $single_term){
        ?>
        <div id="fields-list-selected" data-post_id="<?php echo $post_ID; ?>">
            <?php
            do_action('wp_ajax_fields_selected', $post_ID, $single_term); ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }}
```

Comment: Can you please add the code of your PHP function that is handling the request?

Comment: @BorisKuzmanov --I have edited my code. Please check.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has

```
 var getid = $('#my-categorychecklist input:checked').last().val();
```

see the .last(), that's why you're only getting the last item
Also, why do you have the same thing in getid and matchid?

You need to store the selected categories in an array and loop through them,
try something like:

```
var selected_cats = $('#my-categorychecklist input:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value
})
```

(without the .get())
then loop through them with

```
    selected_cats.forEach(function(element) {
        console.log(element)
      //make sure element has what you're expecting then do you something on element
}
```

Try doing console.log() on each variable and see in your console, if the the variables have the result you're expecting. Make sure that selected_cats has an array of the selected categories

Comment: I have looped it through for but still printing the last one.  like that----   `var i;
        var numberOfTermSelected = termID.length;

        for (i = 0; i<numberOfTermSelected; i++ ){
          
        }`